# Як перекласти "bagging" з машинного навчання?

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни

Неодноразово стикався з терміном **bagging** з розділу машинного навчання, але допоки не знайшов нормального українського перекладу (без прямої транслітерації).

Джерело на вікі - [тут](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_aggregating).

[Українське джерело](http://katanicya.domen.uz.ua/index.php?id=vstup-v-mashinne-navchannya), де описується термін "bagging". Але він з транслітерацією.

Ще [тут](https://dev.by/lenta/main/sem-osnovnyh-ponyatiy-mashinnogo-obucheniya), але тут просто зробили транслітерацію.

По суті, bagging збирає різні варіанти моделей й узагальнює - створюється своєрідна "торба", куди складаються прийнятні варіанти -> "торбування" :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Зайшов на Вікі, подивився на інтервікі, отже, німці використали *bagging*, a корейці, японці і китайці просто транслітерували. І лише іспанці використали синонімічну назву, щось на схоже на **групування бутстрепів** нашою. Тому, як варіант можна **бегінг**.

Власне термін означає алгоритм використовний для уникнення [перенавчання](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F). Тобто спочатку робиться декілька вибірок із повторами, припасовують криву до кожної з них. Всі ці криві дуже хвилясті, бо надто точно відповідають даним. А тоді якимось чином усереднюють між цими кривими, в результаті виходить гладка крива. Дивись зображення для ясності.

[image]

Знов до перекладу, було б класно якось погратись із усередненням між кривими, чи, радше, припасуванням кривої, так, щоб найкраще схопити дані з цілого жмута входових кривих і прямим перекладом **bagging - мішковина, пакування в мішки.**

Comment: дякую за коментар. по суті цей метод і є "торбуванням" :-)  - збираються всі можливі варіанти, на підставі яких створюється узагагальненняю. якщо не буде альтернативи - використаю трансліт.

Comment: @DimonD. Ну, якщо Bilbo Baggings став [Більбо Торбин](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B1%D0%BE_%D0%A2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD), то торбування може й підійти:)

Comment: @DimonD. а що ви перекладаєте? я теж дещо перекладаю, тому цікаво.

Comment: @ Yola
нескільки перекладаю , а вивчаю. а потім треба розтлумачити зацікавленим. тому "торбування" можливо й не такий вже поганий варіант, бо передає ідею, яку досить просто зрозуміти й запам'ятати :-)

Comment: Якшо чесно, на картинці торбу "не видно". Мені нагадує збирання жмута докупи. *В'язання жмута*? *[Жмутов'яз](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B6%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%E2%80%99%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)*?

Comment: @NashBridges Досить непогано, можна оформити як відповідь?

Comment: @Nash Bridges
це лише графічно відображення :-) я відштовхувався від первісного значення "bagging". За своєю суттю в нас є віртуальна "торба" куди все скинули й витягли якийсь узангальнений варіант.

Comment: @DimonD.  у джерелі вказано, що це гра слів: Bagging (**B**ootstrap **agg**regat**ing**), тому *aggregating* все ж був первинним, і дослівний переклад в такому випадку не обов'язковий (якщо взагалі можливий)

Comment: @Nash Bridges
так це певна абревіатура, скорочена в прикольне слово. але при цьому слово може мати цікаві занячення, наприклад "зледарювання" як додаток до "торбування" :-) Ну й саме слово теж передає сутність методу (взагалі). не напоглягаю, що має бути переклад, але чому б теж прикольно б не перекласти :-)